# Laravel - pagination sorting by created_at

Tags: laravel, sorting, date, pagination

So guys I add pagination to my project and I'm almost finishing it, witch by the way is my first project ever, and all I need to do right now is to set pagination by created_at.So I need to put posts from the same day on same page link. Right now it shows me posts from different days on one page. And after that I just need to show price sum of that day. If you know please help me, this would be my first project as a student, I'm still learning. Thank you !!

Here is my HomeController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Post;
use DB;
use Auth;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id())->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate(3);
        return view('home')->with('posts', $posts);
    }


}
```

Here is my home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.theme')

@section('content')
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #EBEBEB;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="mainl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="columna">



                <h1>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</h1>
                <hr>
            </div>

            <div class="columns">
                <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" id="logout"
                onclick="event.preventDefault();
                        document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                    {{ __('LOGOUT') }}
                </a>

                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                    @csrf
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
        </br></br></br>

        @if(count($posts)> 0)
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>BR.KESICE</th>
                    <th>IME I PREZIME</th>
                    <th>BR.TELEFONA</th>
                    <th>POSAO</th>
                    <th>CIJENA</th>
                    <th>PLACANJE</th>
                    <th>POPUST</th>
                    <th>DATUM PREUZ.</th>
                    <th>DATUM IZDAV.</th>
                    <th>SMJENA</th>
                    <th>RADNIK</th>
                    <th>STATUS</th>
                    <th>IZMIJENI</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($posts as $post)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$post->br_kesice}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->ime}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->br_telefona}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->posao}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->cijena}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->placanje}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->popust}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->datum_preuz}}</td>
                    @if($post->status == 1)
                        <td>/</td>
                    @else
                        <td>{{$post->datum_izdav}}</td>
                    @endif
                    <td>{{$post->smjena}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->radnik}}</td>
                    <td>
                        @if($post->status == 0)
                        <span class="label label-primary" id="statusdeaktivan">Deaktivan</span>
                        @elseif($post->status == 1)
                        <span class="label label-success" id="statusaktivan">Aktivan</span>
                        @elseif($post->status == 2)
                        <span class="label label-danger" id="statusdeaktivan">Rejected</span>
                        @else
                        <span class="label label-info" id="statusdeaktivan">Deaktivan</span>
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    @if($post->status == 3)

                    @else
                    <td><a href="posts/{{$post->id}}/edit" class="edit"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                    @endif

                </tr>

                @endforeach
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>UKUPAN IZNOS:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                    <th>KARTICA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'Kartica')->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                    <th>GOTOVINA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'Gotovina')->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                    <th>VIRMAN:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'Virman')->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        {{ $posts->links()}}
        @else
            <p>Trenutno nema unosa.</p>
        @endif
    </div>
@endsection
```

And I found something from past questions here in stack overflow and it's working but I have a problem with that, so

```
public function index()
{
        $posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(10))->get();
        return view('home')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

When I add this `->where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(10))->get();` it shows me all posts from past 10 days but after that 10 days nothing, could I use this but to sort it by all days, not to set maximum days?
I also add this code to my price sum and it is working but as I said just for past 10 days

```
<tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>UKUPAN IZNOS:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(10))->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                    <th>KARTICA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'Kartica')->where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(10))->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                    <th>GOTOVINA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'Gotovina')->where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(10))->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                    <th>VIRMAN:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'Virman')->where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(10))->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
```

Thank you again and I would really appreciate it if you help me with this. It's my first project and I'm very happy about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your current code is doing is taking all the posts, sort it by `created_at` and then show 3 at a time. It doesn't care about what day it is or how many `$post` are there for that particular day.

What I understand that, you want to do is to show it by date. In that case, your query should filter based on date.

What you need to do is pass the date to the controller and fetch only posts from that day. It is a bit tricky. You need to pass today's date to controller.

In HTTP GET method your URL should contain the date. For example, it can be something like `http://example.com/index?date=20190716`. Notice that "date=20190716" part. You can get this in controller. Then you can get the posts of that day by writing,

```
$date = new Carbon(request('date'));
$posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id())
        ->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate(3);
```

Now, what it will do is get only the posts from 16th July, 2019.

This is the main idea. How you pass the date is entirely on you. You can do that in several ways. You can use JS, HTTP GET method and HTTP POST method.

Comment: Ok, so I add this code to my HomeController and it's working fine!Thanks!
Now I can see all posts made today, how can I see other posts made for example yesterday? How can I see all of them?

Comment: How you pass the date depends on your project. In carbon, there is a Carbon::yesterday() function that you can use. You can check out carbon documentation. Also if you are comfortable with JS then you can use that and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public function index()
{
        $posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
        return view('home')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

Comment: Yes but with that I don't get what I want. I need pagination with created_at order where all posts created at same day will be at one pagination link, so on one page.

Comment: So you want to paginate based on day?

Answer (score 0):

Try this also, I hope helps you

```
public function index()
{
        $dateFromUrl = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', request()->date);

        $posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('created_at',$dateFromUrl)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->get();

        $sum = 0;
        foreach($posts as $post){
           $sum+=$post->price;
        }



        return view('home', compact("posts","sum"));
}
```

Comment: When I add this to my code it as first show me $request undefined variable , and then I add ```public function index(Request $request)``` but then it shows me "Data missing". Do you know what is a problem?

Comment: it was my mistake, so I edited this. 
if you get the "Data missing" error, you must convert the "createFromFormat" parameter with your date in URL